# I cant access $scope.variable[index] within ng repeat in angular

Tags: angularjs, indexing, scope

I have a router:

```
.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/allbooks', {
        templateUrl: 'find/showAllMy.html',
        controller: 'controlador'
      }).when('/mybooks', {
        templateUrl: 'find/showAllMy.html',
        controller: 'controlador'
      })
      .when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'find/inputbook.html',
        controller:'controlador'
      })          
}]);
```

A view file, "showAllMy.html":

```
<div id='containerMyBooks' ng-init='MyRequests=0; RequestsForMe=0; '>

  <center><h3>{{titleMyAll}}</h3></center>

  <div id='containerbuttonsrequest'>
      <button class='waves-effect waves-light btn'>Your Trade Request {{MyRequests}}      </button>
      <button class='waves-effect waves-light btn'>Trade Request for you {{RequestsForMe}}</button>
  </div>

  <ul ng-repeat='b in Books' ng-init='tradeLink[$index]=true'>

      <li class='styleLi'>
          <a class='stylelinktrade' ng-show='tradeLink[$index]' href='/#/{{titleMyAll}}' ng-click="trade('yes',$index)"><img class="styleimgtrade" src='../images/trade.png'>trade!</a>
          <a class='stylelinktrade' ng-hide='tradeLink[$index]' href='/#/{{titleMyAll}}' ng-click="trade('no',$index)"><img class="styleimgtrade" src='../images/trade.png'>Cancel trade</a> 
          <img class='styleimgbook' src={{b.img}}>
      </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

And this logic in my controller:

```
$scope.trade = function(yesNo, index) {      
  if (yesNo === 'yes') {
    $scope.MyRequests = $scope.MyRequests + 1;
  } else {
    $scope.MyRequests = $scope.MyRequests - 1;
  }
  console.log('log' + $scope.tradeLink[index]);
  // $scope.tradeLink[0]=!$scope.tradeLink[0];
}
```

But I can't seem to get access to $scope.tradeLink[index] from the view and, instead, am getting an error saying "cannot read property 1 of undefined."

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where is the array $scope.tradeLink defined?  Can you include an example of its contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s because you never initialized `tradeLink` to an array. Adding `tradeLink = []` in your top `ng-init` should fix your bug.

But **that said**, please [refrain from using `ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

> This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`, such as for aliasing special properties of `ngRepeat`, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use [controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope.

Instead, remove all your `ng-init` usages (besides the one with `ng-repeat` which might be relevant) and add this in your controller:

```
$scope.MyRequests = 0;
$scope.RequestsForMe = 0;
$scope.tradeLink = [];
```

Comment: Trank you so much bro! that it and for the quick response

Comment: and thank you for the advice!! i'll take it in consideration in the future